# importing only some parts of a large library, but hiding the library structure for convenience

Tags: python, python-import

Please look at the example. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
# 1. importing from a large package lpack
#    only those parts that are going to be used
from lpack import timers    # defines SomeTimer and other Timers
from lpack import triggers  # defines RegularTrigger and others Triggers
# not importing many many other lpack modules

# 2. in the *same .py file* not having to care
#    about the internal organization of the lpack
mytimer = lpack.SomeTimer()        # i.e. not timers.SomeTimer()
mytrigger = lpack.RegularTrigger()
```

I have no solution. My idea is something like `lpack = timers + triggers` (not literally, of course). An automated way (some kind of desired import side effect) would be the best.

Comment: You can monkeypatch `lpack` after the `import`s with statements like  `lpack.SomeTimer = timers.SomeTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from lpack.timers import *   
from lpack.triggers import *

mytimer = SomeTimer()
mytrigger = RegularTrigger()
```

The disadvantage is that if both packages contain methods with the same name one of them will be overwritten (I expect the second import to overwrite the first). You should also be careful not to have local methods with the same name, as this will lead to conflicts.

Comment: Yes, this way is the problem avoided, but it did not answer my question.